# How to configure guard-slim for non-ruby projects?

Tags: guard, slim-lang

I created a new project and added a Gemfile, including the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'slim'
gem 'sass'
gem "guard-slim"
gem 'guard-sass'
```

Then, after running `bundle install` and `guard init`, a Guardfile was generated.

Inside my Guardfile I have the following code:

```
guard "slim", :input_root => "slim", :output_root => "." do
    watch(%r{^templates/.+(\.slim)$})
end

guard 'sass', :input => 'sass', :output => 'css'
```

If I remove the slim part, my sass is compiled with no problems. But I keep getting an error when trying to run `guard`, which says:

```
Could not load class: "Slim"
```

After trying several times, I removed slim altogether and tryed using Haml instead, and it worked well. I would like to use slim for this project, so how do I get it to work? Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No, I think this version of guard-slim is still incomplete. I transitioned to [Haml](http://haml.info), instead.

Comment: Thank you, will look into guard-slim when I have a chance. Should not be difficult to compare it with guard-haml. Will let you know if I figure it out.